# c++ 2d array leads to Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have a program (below) to build a matrix of distances between points (in my test file there are ~8000 points in 3D space).  So I want a (roughly) 8000x8000 matrix, but when I try to build it using an array of doubles (or floats), I always get a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error.  Any ideas why?  I have 16GB of RAM, so this should be feasible, since 8000 * 8000 * 8 is only roughly 0.5GB.  Also (commented out in code below), I can build the matrix as a vector of vectors, but this is slow - takes around 30 seconds.  As it happens, I only need to record distances less than 1.5, so the matrix is very sparse - no doubt there are better ways of implementation, but it's bugging me that this doesn't work.  Any advice gratefully received!

```
//Get distance matrix from .dms file
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double dist(vector<double> a, vector<double> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) return -1;
    else
    {
        double dist = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) dist += pow(a[i] - b[i], 2);
        return dist;
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    vector<vector<double> > points;
    string line;
    infile.open("1dwr.dms");
    outfile.open("1dwr.mat");
    while (getline(infile,line))
    {
        if ((line.at( line.length() - 1)) != 'A')
        {
            double x[3] = {atof((line.substr(13,8)).c_str()), atof((line.substr(21,9)).c_str()), atof((line.substr(30,9)).c_str())};
            vector<double> point;
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                point.push_back(x[i]);
            }
            points.push_back (point);
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    int len = points.size();
    double dist_matrix[len][len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j<len; j++)
        {
            double d = dist(points[i], points[j]);
            if(d < 2.25)
            {
                dist_matrix[i][j] = sqrt(d);
                dist_matrix[j][i] = sqrt(d);
            }
        }
    }

//  vector<vector<double> > dist_matrix;
//  for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
//  {
//      vector< double> row;
//      for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
//      {
//          double d = dist(points[i], points[j]);
//          if (d < 2.25) row.push_back (sqrt(d));
//          else row.push_back (0);
//      }
//      dist_matrix.push_back (row);
//  }


    outfile.close();
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks.  The step which fails is declaring the variable `double dist_matrix[len][len]` and it fails because the variable `len` is too large.

Comment: Stack Overflow most probably!

Comment: OK - so why does it lead to a stack overflow?  Even the following code on its own gives the same error:
`int main() {
    double matrix[2000][2000] = {{0}};
    return 0;
}`

Comment: The stack is limited. Try heapifying it like `std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(2000,std::vector<double>(2000));`

Comment: VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are not standard C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Thanks - matrix is now built in around 15 seconds.  This still seems a long time, although I shouldn't complain about a factor of 2 improvement!  And the original Python implementation took 20 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that statements `int len = points.size(); double dist_matrix[len][len]` lets the program create a `8000 x 8000`-array of doubles on the *stack*, and the size of the stack is - compared to the heap - rather limited. So it is very likely that you get a "stack overflow", indicated probably by a "Bad access"-error. If you try your code with `80x80`, it will probably work.

So for `len==8000`, you'd have to create the array on the heap; yet there is - to my knowledge - no way to do a statement like `double x[len][len] = new double...` if `len` is not known at compile time.

You could come around this by allocating a 1D-array of size `len * len` and calculate the "2D"-index manually, as shown in the code below:

```
int main() {

    int len = 8000;
    double *dist_matrix = new double[len*len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j<len; j++)
        {
            size_t idx = len*i + j;
            dist_matrix[idx] = 5.0;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Dropping this link as a demonstration of a convenient wrapper for the above: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: Thanks Stephan - that approach gives me similar speeds (around 15 seconds) to using a vector of vectors as per πάντα ῥεῖ's suggestion.  I still think the timings are slow, though - there are around 10^8 distances to calculate, but I reckon my processor should be able to give me 7*10^10 FLOPS...

Comment: Solved this a while back outside C++ in the end.  The scipy function `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()` builds the matrix in under 0.1s.  Slightly unsatisfactory not to be able to code up something efficient myself, but no need to re-invent the wheel